# Display a master-detail view. yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am looking for some way to implement the following thing with `yii2`:

Lets imagine we have the following structure: - rawMaterial table. - rawMaterialentry table

Each rawMaterial -> has 1 or more entry.

What I want to do is to display on a view, the details of an rawMaterial, and under it, a gridview of all the entries it has. In some other words, a master-detail view.

My problem is that in the gridview of the Entries, which belongs to the current rawMaterial, when i try to update, view or delete any of the entries it takes me to the rawMaterial instead to the Entry views

Comment: can you show your code of model,view and controller.

Comment: it is not possible to provide yo full code we can guide you or give you the solution where you are mistaken, so please try to make your question more describable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply set [`controller`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$controller-detail) in your `ActionColumn` config.

> The ID of the controller that should handle the actions specified here. If not set, it will use the currently active controller.

e.g. :

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'controller' => 'entry',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to Change `ActionButtonColumn` of Your GridView to provide an appropriate Url. Otherwise GridView will use the current contoller.

```
[
'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
'template' => '{update}{view}',
'buttons' => [
    'update' => function($url ,$model){
        $url= Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['/entry/update', 'id' => $model->id ]);
        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">', $url);
    },
    'view' => function($url ,$model){
        $url= Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['/entry/view', 'id' => $model->id ]);
        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">', $url);
    }
]
```

]

Comment: `entry-controller` isn't correct, it should be `$url= Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/entry/update', 'id' => $model->id ]);`. The leading slash makes it a url **not** relative to the current controller